# How to route https request before ListenAndServeTLS

Tags: go

Before I know which certificate files to use, I need to check the request Host, how to do that ?

I can't call

```
http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "cerfile", "certkey", mux)
```

because the cert files and "mux" to use depends on the request host address, which is only available in the handler!

and of course I should only use the 443 port!

Can this be done with http package alone ?

Comment: Use `http.Server` with a custom `tls.Config` that has a `GetCertificate` func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Burak Serdar comment, you could custom `GetCertificate` of [`tls.Config`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config) to return the specific certificate by different host.

Sample Code

```golang
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    cfg := &tls.Config{
        GetCertificate: func(info *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
            // get certificate by info.ServerName

        },
    }
    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:      ":443",
        Handler:   mux,
        TLSConfig: cfg,
    }
    fmt.Println(srv.ListenAndServeTLS("defaulttls.crt", "defaulttls.key"))
```

About how to get a certificate by `ClientHelloInfo`, you could refer to [autocert sample codes](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/acme/autocert/autocert_test.go#L916)

Comment: Yes, it was possible to get the correct cert files using the "info.ServerName", thank you!